# How to reverse words in a string but keep punctuation in the right place?

Tags: java, string, reverse

I have written the following code to reverse an input String:

```
  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Please enter a sentence:");
  String sentence = s.nextLine();

  String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
  String reversedSentence = "";

  for(int i = words.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
  {
      reversedSentence += words[i] + " ";
  }

  System.out.println(reversedSentence);
```

However it is not giving me the result I want. I need the punctuation to be part of the word it is attached to, but still to switch to the right side of the word. For example if you input

> “The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog”

I want the output to be

> “dog lazy the over jumps fox brown quick The”

What I am actually getting is:

> dog” lazy the over jumps fox brown quick “The

Comment: You are only interested for the quotes at the start and the end ? What about punctuation in the middle of the sentence ?

Comment: Looks like a special case you'll have to deal with. You could put an `if (words[0].contains("\""))` to check to see if a double quote exists. You may want to do this after your for loop.

Comment: Before 'System.out.println(reversedSentence);' add line 'reversedSentence = "\"" + reversedSentence.replace("\"", "") + "\"";'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to handle double quotes at the start and end of the input, just reverse the substring and add them later. E.g.

```
if (sentence.startsWith("\"") && sentence.endsWith("\"")) {
    sentence = sentence.substring(1, sentence.length()-1);
}
```

and finally after splitting, reversing and concatenating print:

```
System.out.println('"' + reversedSentence + '"');
```

Also 2 recommendations :

1) Your for loop leaves a trailing space. Don't add a space for the last word
2) You should use a `StringBuilder` to concatenate strings. E.g.

```
StringBuilder reversedSentence = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = words.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    reversedSentence.append(words[i]).append(' ');
}
reversedSentence.append(words[0]);
System.out.println('"' + reversedSentence.toString() + '"');
```

Comment: In the top part of this answer, the substring parameters are incorrect because substrings accept (int inclusive, int exclusive) so therefore it should be:

if (sentence.startsWith("\"") && sentence.endsWith("\"") {
    sentence = sentence.substring(1, sentence.length()-1);
}

Answer (score 1):

If the punctuation opens and closes as well. Like in your example. You could use something like this:

It's very dirty. I'll edit it later. I don't do java much.

```
    String[][] punctuations = new String[][] {
            {"(", ")"},
            {"“", "”"}
    };

    for (String[] punctuation : punctuations) {
        if (sentence.contains(punctuation[0])) {
            int index_0 = sentence.indexOf(punctuation[0]);
            int index_of_next_space = sentence.indexOf(" ", index_0);
            String old_string_0 = sentence.substring(index_0, index_of_next_space);
            String new_string_0 = old_string_0.replace(punctuation[0], "") + punctuation[1];

            int index_1 = sentence.indexOf(punctuation[1]);
            int index_of_last_space = sentence.lastIndexOf(" ", index_1);
            String old_string_1 = sentence.substring(index_of_last_space+1, index_1 + 1);
            String replaced_string_1 = punctuation[0] + old_string_1.replace(punctuation[1], "");
            sentence = sentence.replace(old_string_0, new_string_0);
            sentence = sentence.replace(old_string_1, replaced_string_1);
        }
    }
```

Now reverse your string.

Input:

> “The (quick brown's) fox jumps over the lazy dog”

Output:

> “dog lazy the over jumps fox (brown's quick) The”

This can be improved. Like I said before, I don't do java much :/.

Answer (score 0):

Break the string into array and use [Collections.reverse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)) as follows:

```
public class StringReverse {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a sentence:");
        String sentence = s.nextLine();
        String[] array = sentence.replaceAll("\\“|”", "").split(" ");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
        Collections.reverse(list);
        array = (String[]) list.toArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            sb.append(array[i]).append(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(sentence.charAt(0)
                + sb.toString().replaceAll(" $", "")
                + sentence.charAt(sentence.length() - 1));
        s.close();
    }
}
```

With **Java 8** [Arrays.stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-), it is as simple as:

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class StringReverse {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a sentence:");
    String sentence = s.nextLine();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Arrays.stream(sentence.replaceAll("\\“|”", "").split(" "))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayDeque::new))
            .descendingIterator()
            .forEachRemaining(e -> sb.append(e).append(" "));
    System.out.println(sentence.charAt(0)
            + sb.toString().replaceAll(" $", "")
            + sentence.charAt(sentence.length() - 1));
    s.close();
}
```

Comment: Next time read the question before answering.

Comment: @RaghavSharma: missed the quotes because of code formatting issues, anyways fixed it now!