# Java Reverse a sentence but not punctuation

Tags: java, string, reverse

Input: My name is Bob.

Output: Bob is name My.

I have seen plenty of examples on how to reverse each word and then word sequence in a sentence. However, I do not think I have seen one that I want-example above. This forum was not helpful, because it only focuses on double quote on start and end of a sentence: [How to reverse words in a string but keep punctuation in the right place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33899575/how-to-reverse-words-in-a-string-but-keep-punctuation-in-the-right-place)

What I tried

```
public void rev2(String str) {
    String[] arrStr = str.split(" ");
    for (int i = arrStr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (!arrStr[i].contains(".")) {
            System.out.print(arrStr[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t = new Test();
    t.rev2("My name is Bob.");
}
```

The code above does not work as expected. I probably can convert each string to char and use Character.isAlphabet() or may be use pattern?

I could use some ideas. Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Describe _does not work as expected_. What does it do that you didn't expect?

Comment: What about removing the punctuation, reversing the words, and then adding it back? Then you don't need to explicitly look for it during your reverse logic.

Comment: Will there only ever be punctuation at the end of the String? Or can the String contain more punctuation, for example "My name is Bob. I am happy." ?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis is name My  is printed.

Comment: @DarkMatter I was thinking of making it handle punctuation not only in the end, a punctuation can be anywhere.

Comment: Either full stop is the only punctuation and is always at the end and is to remain there, or punctuation may appear anywhere. If the latter, give input examples that have multiple punctuation characters, including apostrophes within and around words if required, and show expected outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that works within the constraints of the question (some of which are assumed):

```
public void rev2(String str) {
    String[] arrStr = str.split(" ");
    for (int i = arrStr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        boolean punct = i <= 0 || arrStr[i - 1].contains(".");
        if (!arrStr[i].contains(".")) {
            System.out.print(arrStr[i]);
        } else {
            System.out.print(arrStr[i].substring(0, arrStr[i].length() - 1));
        }
        System.out.print((punct ? ". " : " "));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tester t = new Tester();
    t.rev2("My name is Bob. I am happy.");
}
```

Explanation:

The boolean punct looks ahead to see if the next element contains a ".". If so, we are on a sentence boundry and so added a . after the current word. If not, we just put a space. We also add a "." if we are on the last element in the array.

Output:
`happy am I. Bob is name My.`

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do regarding punctuation is keep the period at the end of the sentence, you can print the words followed by a space or by the period depending on whether they are the first word or not, and you can remove the period from the last word by calling `substring()`. Something like this:

```
public class Test {
    public void rev2(String str) {
        String[] arrStr = str.split(" ");
        for (int i = arrStr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (!arrStr[i].contains(".")) {
                System.out.print(arrStr[i] + (i == 0 ? "." : " "));
            } else {
                System.out.print(arrStr[i].substring(0, arrStr[i].length() - 1) + " ");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.rev2("My name is Bob.");
    }
}
```

**Output:** Bob is name My.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a less verbose code:

```
var list = Arrays.asList("My name is Bob".split(" "));
Collections.reverse(list);
list.stream().map(str -> str.concat(" ")).forEach(System.out::print);
```